# Workflow for sharing inventory of stormwater network in Open Source GIS?

Tags: open-source-gis, software-recommendations, arcpad, workflow

Our agency has collaborated with six townships and one city for preparing an inventory of stormwater network.

We are using ArcGIS 10 (2 ArcView licenses) and ArcPad 7.1 (stuck with it since our Mobilemapper CX is running on Windows CE).

We are using ESRI File based Geodatabase (chose it because it allows multiple readers and one editor per feature datasets and it has one feature dataset for every political subdivision). We have finished 25% of the project.

My primary concerns are:

a) We cannot edit same feature dataset at a time. Mostly, my intern and I collect and edit data for same area/region at a time.

b) Collecting data in the field is not efficient enough since we cannot see each others edits. (using ArcPad Data Manager)

c) Sharing data with client is not a smooth task (converting the data into KML format so that it can be viewed on ArcGIS Explorer).

I understand that the solution to my problem is ArcSDE and ArcGIS server but we don't have funding. We want to finish the project ASAP.

Please recommend a workflow and open source software where we can work and share the data with clients more efficiently.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

a) We cannot edit same feature dataset at a time. Mostly, my intern and I collect and edit data for same area/region at a time.
**use 2 file geodatabases - with an append (every day or hour)**

b) Collecting data in the field is not efficient enough since we cannot see each others edits. (using ArcPad Data Manager)
**do you have cell phone coverage? upload data from arcpad via laptop**

c) Sharing data with client is not a smooth task (converting the data into KML format so that it can be viewed on ArcGIS Explorer).
**Use Google Earth - KML Native - with network link (auto -refresh)**

A standard network link is a uni-directional link: data flows only from the server to Google Earth. The view-based refresh enables bi-directional communication. When the view-based refresh is active, Google Earth returns the view coordinates to the server at a specified time. This may be every n seconds, minutes, or hours, or once a certain amount of time has elapsed since the view stopped moving. See  in the KML 2.2 Reference. 
http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kml_tut.html

**cost - one laptop* - pc/server* for kml serving (free or paid services online - Amazon EC2)**
*might be already existing

Answer (score 1):

Using ArcPad you could create an FTP site.

Send your updates to the ftp, from the ftp have an append/[check in] tool written to the file GDB, and another one to extract the latest information and then FTP back to yourself.

People have been doing it like this for years prior to Server and it is all relatively easy to install.